# Why is the readonly attribute not implemented for select?

Tags: html, html-select, readonly-attribute

The title says it all...

I am *not* looking for answers on a workaround (such as disable select / hidden input); I am just asking: why is it that way?

Comment: <select readonly="readonly">...</select>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a real answer for this other than the developers decided that's how the API should be.

My take on it would be that "readonly" implies that you're going to do some typing. Perhaps the developers did not think that the select element really took keyboard input. And therefore chose to use the "disabled" attribute instead.

Comment: The typing thing could be the reason!
I disagree with the "disabled" part though because it has a very different meaning (it does not send the value when submitting the form)

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful in forms.. for example you want the user to tick a checkbox or answer a question  before they can actually input data into an input box. It helps the user to "keep on the right track" so that data can be properly recorded based on certain preferences.

Nevertheless, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

```
The readonly attribute can be set to keep a user from changing the value until some other conditions have been met (like selecting a checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript can remove the readonly value, and make the input field editable.
```

Also this link have a practical example

http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/02/12/html-disabled-or-readonly/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Also, your second link shows some code that doesn't work, which is the whole point of this question. Have you tried to use readonly on a select?

Comment: take a look at the question heading and actual question ask " Is there any scenario [reference made to readonly] where this would make sense?". Is this not ambigous? ..This is how I understood  it (I think the question  is unclear)..

Comment: I removed that last question...